# How to avoid focusing on the window when sending a mouse message via SendMessage?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I am working on a project with a farm automation in a web game on Unity 3D. Game works in Google Chrome browser. I tried to emulate the mouse using the SendMessage function in WinApi, but there was a problem that when program sent a mouse message, Google Chrome window focused. How make Chrome window don't focus when emulating mouse via SendMessage?

Comment: You can't reliably fake input using `SendMessage`, see the many thousands of similar posts on this site.

Comment: Unless you are a *very* experienced developer, cheating tends to be much more time consuming than actually playing the game.

Comment: I tried SendMessage to send to the window, but it does not make the window focus. And you need to pay attention to: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513)